# Alternative for UIGetScreenImage()

Tags: ios, screenshot, retina-display

The screen shot image returned from the apple's private API `UIGetScreenImage()` is **640x1136** in retina display but other alternative code gives only 320x568. Is it possible to take screen shot in @2x mode?

**This is the code I am using**

```
-(UIImage*)getScreenShot:(CALayer*)layer 
{
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, NO, 0.0);
        [layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return image;
}

   [self getScreenShot:self.window.layer];
```

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of answer about how to get screen images. In your case I guess that the problem is that using the private API you get the whole screen, in the latter (but if you don't show a little of code is hard to say) you are rendering only a part of the view. You have 2 options with public API:

- `renderInContext`
- `drawViewHierarchy` (only iOS7 and probably >)

This snippet sum up the 2 methods, it's a a UIView category, so you should send this message on UIView objects (or subclasses). Sending it to the window you get the full screen

```
- (UIImage *) imageByRenderingViewOpaque:(BOOL) yesOrNO {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, yesOrNO, 0);

    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:)]) {
        [self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.bounds afterScreenUpdates:NO];
    }
    else {
        [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    }
    UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return resultingImage;
}
- (UIImage *) imageByRenderingView{
    return [self imageByRenderingViewOpaque:NO];
}
```

Comment: thats basically what I use and it worked fine for me too

Comment: it differs for opengl content but for UIKit stuff this is fine

Comment: Yes, unfortunately no opengl and no AVCapturePreviewLayer :(

Comment: Daij-Djan Have you tried to print the size of the returned image in retina display? It doesn't give the size in @2x mode that means the screen shot size is just 320X568 only. But the private api gives 640X1136. So if I used that image in UIImageView it looks very clear. But the image returns from the above code is some what blur.

Comment: The private API returns a CGIMageRef, that doesn't have the knowledge about the scale of the screen, so that's correct, it returns the real pixels. If you ask a scale to a UIImage you get the size taking scale into account (you can ask it into the debugger or log)

Comment: @Andrea. I can get the scale but the real problem is, I need image with size 640X1136 in retina display. Can you get me? So only if i use that image in another uiimageview it will be clear

Comment: I get you, but you aren't getting me. Images with the method I exposed are automatically set for retina. If you inspect the CGImage property of the returned UIImage the size would be 1136x640. The UIImage has the half as half the size because it sets the scale at 2. In UIKit you should work with points non pixels and on current retina displays a point is double  a pixel. The doc are pretty clear